# XCode manual UI test cases

Tags: xcode, unit-testing

I want to test a view controller and a model class.

The way I do this today is:

- create a new "testing" view controller in the storyboard
- create a quick UIViewController subclass that instant images the model and then presents the view controller I want to test
- move the entry point on the storyboard to the testing VC and run
- manually play with the GUI to make sure it is right*

Is there a better way to do this, possible using the built-in testing framework, which does not pollute my storyboard and which does not require creating lots of extra VCs?

Note the * step is good, I don't want to change that.

Comment: I think someone downvoted you because you accidently posted duplicate questions. See if you can remove on of them.

Comment: Sorry, double submit. Other post deleted.

Comment: To clarify, I have created automated UI tests in the past (especially for screenshots -- fastlane). But here I am asking about MANUAL testing. I just want it to open so I can inspect it by hand. Not trying to over-engineer it in this situation.

Comment: Basically I'm looking for an entry point into the program for quick testing rather than setting the storyboard entry point to a dummy new VC.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better way to do this, possible using the built-in testing framework, which does not pollute my storyboard and which does not require creating lots of extra VCs?

Yes, Xcode provides a UI testing framework for writing functional tests against your user interface. It leverages [Accessibilty](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Accessibility_on_iPhone/Accessibility_on_iPhone.html) to manipulate user interface elements programmatically. You can get a good introduction to automated UI testing from the [WWDC video on the subject](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-406/). Certainly, you shouldn't need to modify your storyboard or create new view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
[self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:60 handler:nil];
```

This makes everything wait 60 seconds while you play with it. Who cares what the return value is. You are doing this inspection manually.